# not displaying validation messages while click on button in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have created a login page i want it to display validation messages if user doesnt enter username and password on click of button,i have written code as below

Homecontroller.cs

```
  public ActionResult Login()
    {
        // ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(logintable p)
    {
       abEntities db = new abEntities();
        List<sp_logindata_Result> data = db.sp_logindata(p.Username, p.Password).ToList();

        Session["LogedUserID"] = data.First().UserID.ToString();
        Session["UserNme"] = data.First().FullName.ToString();
        int typeVal = data.First().Usertype;

        if (typeVal == 1)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("page1");
        }
        else if (typeVal == 2)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("page2");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Error");
        }



        return View(data);
    }
```

logintable.cs

```
 public partial class logintable
{
    public logintable()
    {
        this.PerformanceDetails = new HashSet<PerformanceDetail>();
        this.EvaluationDetails = new HashSet<EvaluationDetail>();
    }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee name is required")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PerformanceDetail> PerformanceDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EvaluationDetail> EvaluationDetails { get; set; }
}
```

login.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Username)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

}

what i am missing here so it is not displaying messages.

Comment: Have you enabled client side validation and included the relevant scripts? And in the POST method, you need to check if `ModelState` is valid - `if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(p); }`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke i didnt added relevant scripts, thanks now it worls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't happen automatically

You need to follow at minimum certain steps:

1. Add validation Rules to your Model [You already done]
2. Add the scripts that will take care of client side validation (unobstrusive validation) [Required].

   ```
   @section Scripts {
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
   }
   ```
3. Add the bundle in BundleConfig.cs file, under App_Start folder

   ```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
   "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*", 
    ~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
   ```